# Screen recording on the Raspberry Pi 4 in Rasbian

Tags: pi-4, software-recommendation, screen-recorder

I've tried Kazam, RecordMyDesktop, Simple Screen Recorder, and Vokoscreen on the Raspberry Pi, but none of these screen recorders work well and work properly. The best one is RecordMyDesktop but it has a problem where the screen gets tinted pink on the recording output.

What RecordMyDesktop does well is that it doesn't encode on-the-fly but rather waits until the recording is done, so the framerate doesn't suffer.

I'm looking for a screen recording solution similar to this that gets a high frame rate, but without the tint. Perhaps is it possible for FFMPEG to record the screen as normal, but not encode on the fly? Or maybe is there another screen recording solution that is fast on the Raspberry Pi? I know that it's not very good hardware but if there's a working fork or similar program to RecordMyDesktop maybe this would work well?

TL;DR Is there a fast and working screen recorder for the Pi? Or perhaps an option to not encode a recording on-the-fly?

Answer (score 2):

## Use FFmpeg

FFmpeg runs on C so that should give you the best possible performance if you're using a Pi. It will still only be a small upgrade though it's worth giving a try.

## Record the VNC Window

This can give you extremly good results if you use an wired connection from your laptop and Pi to your router (miles better than FFmpeg). You can still do this on Wifi, but it will stutuer on slower connections. [Set up VNC](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/). Install OBS on your laptop. Create a window capture for VNC Viewer and start recording. Note: if your laptop is a lower end one you might have to close all the other apps to get good performance.

## Capturing HDMI Output

This method will give you the best possible quality. It's pretty similar to the one above. You'd buy somthing like this:
[image: HDMI capture card]
You can search "HDMI capture card" to find something similar. You would then use OBS on your laptop to record the output. Unless you think you'll be doing this often do not use this method. It costs as much as a Pi Zero just to get one of these.

[A Raspberry Pi Forum discussion](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=174402)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try FFMPEG by itself before, but it seemed to be even slower. I also thought of the VNC trick but wanted local software, though now I do think it would work better than direct solutions, due to saving the CPU time for other apps.